# Thoughts on Approach to Provide Real Time Updates Between FastApi <> React (Using Firebase Firestore)

Tags: reactjs, fastapi

*Planning a feature to provide realtime updates from an API to a frontend React app. Interested if this approach is a good idea or if there is a better somewhat easy way to accomplish this (as I'm a relatively new developer)?

It's data upload application / cleaning application that:

1. Accepts input values on the frontend React app
2. Sends the inputs to a server built on FastApi (Python) w/ Hypercorn

I want to provide real-time updates on events happening on the backend to provide percentage completion / what the backend is currently doing / etc... on the frontend app.

What I'm thinking about doing is use firestore to accomplish this since you can have real-time data updates on the React frontend based on changes to Firestore objects.

The flow would be something like :

1. On frontend, create a document that has an ID passed to the backend on the initial POST request
2. Then have the backend API update the same Firestore doc created by the frontend while things are occurring - using the ID passed to the API to identify/modify the Firestore doc.
3. Since the React app will be using a real-time view of the firestore object, it'll provide real-time updates based on whatever is found within the object.

Planning to have the objects look something like this:

```
{ 
   last_event_time: `Date object`,
   current_event: "Some message about current step",
   percent_complete: "20%"
}
```

I mostly want to just ensure I'm not making a mistake here / going down a less than ideal path to accomplish the goal of having real-time frontend updates passed from the FastAPi backend.

Interested in anyones thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully create the app using the above mentioned setup - for anyone who is curious.

Worked just fine!

Only difference is I put the events in a database object so I just needed to update the "last_event_time" and "step" - then got the "current_event" using the database object with the steps listed per tool